# Second OpenWRT network isn't getting an IP address

Tags: firewall, openwrt

## Goal

I'd like to have two LANs: `lan0` and `lan1`.  `lan0` is unencrypted traffic; `lan1` will be an always-active VPN.  I haven't configured the VPN, so it's currently just a second unencrypted network.

I'm hoping to configure it as such:

[image]

## Symptoms

Unfortunately, `lan1` (named `LAN1_INTERFACE` in the configuration files) isn't working.

- can't join WiFi network:

[image]

- lan1 interface (LAN1_INTERFACE) doesn't have an IP addres:

[image]

I suspect that the firewall isn't properly configured.

What am I missing?  Do I have any other issues that need to be addressed?

## Configuration files

`/etc/config/network`:

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd22:91e8:0e0f::/48'

config interface 'wan'
  option ifname 'eth1.201'
    option proto 'pppoe'
    option username 'user_name'
    option password 'password'
    option ipv6 '0'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth1'
    option _orig_bridge 'false'
    option mtu '1492'

config interface 'lan'
  option ifname 'eth0'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
  option _orig_ifname 'eth0 wlan0'
    option _orig_bridge 'true'

config interface 'lan1_interface'
  option ifname 'eth2'
  option force_link '1'
  option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.2.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
  option _orig_ifname 'eth2 wlan1'
  option _orig_bridge 'true'

config interface 'vpn_interface'
  option ifname 'tun0'
  option proto 'none'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 1 2 3 5'
    option vid '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '2'
    option ports '4 6'
    option vid '2'
```

`/etc/config/wireless`:

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '36'
    option hwmode '11a'
    option path 'platform/soc/soc:pcie-controller/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0'
    option htmode 'VHT80'
    option disabled '0'
    option txpower '23'
    option country 'US'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option disabled '0'
    option encryption 'psk2+tkip+aes'
    option key 'password'
    option network 'lan'
    option ssid 'Router'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '11'
    option country 'US'
    option hwmode '11g'
    option path 'platform/soc/soc:pcie-controller/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    option disabled '0'
    option txpower '19'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio1'
    option mode 'ap'
    option disabled '0'
    option encryption 'psk2+tkip+aes'
    option key 'password'
    option network 'lan1_interface'
    option ssid 'Router [VPN]'
```

`/etc/config/dhcp`:

```
config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded '1'
    option boguspriv '1'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    option localservice '1'
    option nonwildcard '0'
    option domain 'lan'
    option port '5353'
    option dhcpscript '/etc/resolver/dhcp_host_domain_ng.py'

config dhcp 'lan'
    option interface 'lan'
    option start '100'
    option limit '150'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option dhcpv6 'server'
    option ra 'server'
    option ra_management '1'
    list dhcp_option '6,192.168.1.1'

config dhcp 'wan'
    option interface 'wan'
    option ignore '1'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
    option maindhcp '0'
    option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
    option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'

config dhcp 'lan1_interface'
    option start '100'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option limit '150'
    option interface 'lan1_interface'
    list dhcp_option '6,192.168.2.1'
```

`/etc/config/firewall`:

```
config defaults
    option syn_flood '1'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'

#
# includes
#
config include
    option path '/etc/firewall.user'

config include
    option path '/usr/share/firewall/turris'
    option reload '1'

config include
    option path '/etc/firewall.d/with_reload/firewall.include.sh'
    option reload '1'

config include
    option path '/etc/firewall.d/without_reload/firewall.include.sh'
    option reload '0'

config include 'miniupnpd'
    option type 'script'
    option path '/usr/share/miniupnpd/firewall.include'
    option family 'any'
    option reload '1'

#
# zones
#
config zone
    option name 'wan'
    option network 'wan wan6'
    option input 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'

config zone
    option name 'vpn_zone'
    option network 'vpn_interface'
    option input 'REJECT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'

config zone
    option name 'lan'
    option network 'lan'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'ACCEPT'

config zone
    option name 'lan1_zone'
    option network 'lan1_interface'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'ACCEPT'

#
# fowarding
#

config forwarding
    option dest 'wan'
    option src 'lan'

config forwarding
    option dest 'vpn_zone'
    option src 'lan1_zone'

config forwarding
    option dest 'wan'
    option src 'lan1_zone'

#
# IPv4 rules
#
config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCP-Renew'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '68'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option family 'ipv4'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-Ping'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option icmp_type 'echo-request'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-IGMP'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'igmp'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

#
# IPv6 rules
#
config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCPv6'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
    option src_port '547'
    option dest_ip 'fe80::/10'
    option dest_port '546'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-MLD'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
    list icmp_type '130/0'
    list icmp_type '131/0'
    list icmp_type '132/0'
    list icmp_type '143/0'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Input'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    list icmp_type 'router-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'router-advertisement'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-advertisement'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Forward'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest '*'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

#
# rules
#
config rule
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option proto 'esp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option dest_port '500'
    option proto 'udp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option proto 'tcp udp'
    option dest_port '5353'
    option name 'Allow Guest DNS Access'
    option src 'lan1_zone'

config rule
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '67-68'
    option name 'Allow Guest DHCP Access'
    option src 'lan1_zone'
```

** edit **

Router: [Turris Omnia](https://omnia.turris.cz/en/)

Should the second LAN's `dhcp_option` really be `'6,192.168.2.1'` or `'6,192.168.1.1'`?  I don't understand what the `6` does, either.

Comment: What router are you using?

Comment: [Turris Omnia](https://omnia.turris.cz/en/)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question about the dhcp_option, the '6,' is a directive to the dhcp server to push the listed ip addresses as DNS server(s) for the client to use. Each option for the dhcp server to push to the client has a numeric directive and 6 is the directive for DNS server(s).

Comment: Is there a list of these directives?  Am I using it correctly for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by making a few changes:

`/etc/config/network`:

```
config interface 'lan'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth0 eth2 wlan0 wlan1' # needed?
    option _orig_bridge 'true' # needed?
    option ifname 'eth0'

config interface 'lan1_interface'
    option enabled '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option bridge_empty '1'
    option _orig_ifname 'wlan1' # needed?
    option _orig_bridge 'true' # needed?
    option ifname 'eth2'
    option ipaddr '192.168.2.1'
```